# min max messed up in my Python code--what is wrong

Tags: python, max, min

The min/max messed up in my code below, I have input Point(-1239, -4045), Point(1061, -2745), instead of getting bottom=-4045, I got -2745; and for another input Point(976, 2614), Point(2920, 4524), I got left as 2920 instead of 976... Here is a screenshot of the output

[image]

```
import sys

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Rect(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        print p1.x, p2.x, p1.y, p2.y
        self.left   = min(p1.x, p2.x)
         self.right  = max(p1.x, p2.x)
        self.bottom = min(p1.y, p2.y)
        self.top    = max(p1.y, p2.y)
        print 'left %s right %s bottom %s top %s' %(self.left,self.right,self.bottom, self.top)
```

Comment: Your code works for me in Python 3 once I put parens around the prints and fixed that extra space before `self.right`.

Comment: Have it fixed, python regard these numbers as string, so it messed up. 
    self.x = float(x)
    self.y = float(y)

Comment: @SZ maybe write an answer to your question with that information...